# Python how do i send multiple files in the email. I can send 1 file but how to send more than 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, email

I have the following code to send a html file SeleniumTestReport_part1.html in an email in Python.
I want to send more than 1 file in the email.  How do can i do this?

The files I want to send are:
SeleniumTestReport_part1.html
SeleniumTestReport_part2.html
SeleniumTestReport_part3.html

My code to send 1 file is:

```
def send_selenium_report():
    fileToSend = r"G:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\SeleniumTestReport_part1.html"
    with open(fileToSend, "rt") as f:
        text = f.read()
    msg = MIMEText(text, "html")
    msg['Subject'] = "Selenium ClearCore_Regression_Test_Report_Result"
    msg['to'] = "4_server_dev@company.com"
    msg['From'] = "system@company.com"

    s = smtplib.SMTP()
    s.connect(host=SMTP_SERVER)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    s.close()
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: So you want to merge multiple html documents into one? Or are you trying to figure out how to create email attachments?

Comment: My code above reads from 1 html file and writes it to the message part of the email.  I would like to read from multiple files and write it to the message.  Attaching the multiple files would be good too.  Thanks

Comment: This is tagged [tag:python-2.x] so I'm reluctant to post a proper Python 3 answer. Visitors from the future might want to note that the `email` library was overhauled in Python 3.6 and now new code should definitely not use the legacy `MIMEMultipart` and `MIMEText` etc classes. Probably start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) In very brief, just create an `EmailMessage` and `add_attachment` as many times as you like.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to attach files to the email you can use just iterate over files and attach them to the message. You also may want to add some text to the body. 
Here is the code:

```
import smtplib
import os
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

def send_selenium_report():
    dir_path = "G:/test_runners/selenium_regression_test_5_1_1/TestReport"
    files = ["SeleniumTestReport_part1.html", "SeleniumTestReport_part2.html", "SeleniumTestReport_part3.html"]

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['To'] = "4_server_dev@company.com"
    msg['From'] = "system@company.com"
    msg['Subject'] = "Selenium ClearCore_Regression_Test_Report_Result"

    body = MIMEText('Test results attached.', 'html', 'utf-8')  
    msg.attach(body)  # add message body (text or html)

    for f in files:  # add files to the message
        file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, f)
        attachment = MIMEApplication(open(file_path, "rb").read(), _subtype="txt")
        attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment', filename=f)
        msg.attach(attachment)

    s = smtplib.SMTP()
    s.connect(host=SMTP_SERVER)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    print 'done!'
    s.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble with adding files. Just incase someone has a problem with the code: `attachment = MIMEApplication(open(file_path, "rb").read(), _subtype="txt")` works to resolve encoding issue.

Answer (score 9):

I have implemented this for sending mail from gmail.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders

def send_mail_gmail(username,password,toaddrs_list,msg_text,fromaddr=None,subject="Test mail",attachment_path_list=None):

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    s.starttls()
    s.login(username, password)
    #s.set_debuglevel(1)
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    sender = fromaddr
    recipients = toaddrs_list
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    if fromaddr is not None:
        msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
    if attachment_path_list is not None:
        for each_file_path in attachment_path_list:
            try:
                file_name=each_file_path.split("/")[-1]
                part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
                part.set_payload(open(each_file_path, "rb").read())

                Encoders.encode_base64(part)
                part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment' ,filename=file_name)
                msg.attach(part)
            except:
                print "could not attache file"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(msg_text,'html'))
    s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

You can pass multiple address as element of  `toaddrs_list` to whom you want to send mail and multiple attachments files names with their path  in `attachment_path_list`.